# Elastic Beanstalk ebextensions Restart Not Resuming

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a command that needs to restart the computer in on of my ebextensions files under container_commands

01_Rename.config:

```
container_commands:
  01-RenameComputer:
    command: powershell.exe .\\RenameComputer.ps1
    ignoreErrors: false
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
```

RenameComputer.ps1:

```
$instanceId = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
If ($env:COMPUTERNAME -ne $instanceId) {
    Try {
        Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 1000 -EntryType Information -Message "Instance $instanceId's computer name is not sync'd with the instance id. Renaming computer."
        Rename-Computer -NewName $instanceId
        Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 1000 -EntryType Information -Message "Computer renamed. Restarting..."
        Restart-Computer
    }
    Catch [Exception] {
        Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 2000 -EntryType Error -Message "An error occurred renaming $instanceId. $($_.Exception)"
    }
}
Else {
    Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 1000 -EntryType Information -Message "Instance $instanceId's computer name is already sync'd with the instance id."
}
```

but when RenameComputer runs and restarts the computer, my next container_commands config file never runs (the deployment doesn't resume):

02_JoinDomain.config

```
container_commands:
  01-JoinDomain:
    command: powershell.exe .\\JoinDomain.ps1
    ignoreErrors: false
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
```

JoinDomain.ps1:

```
Import-Module AWSPowerShell

$instanceId = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")

If ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN -ne 'mydomain.com') {
    Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 1000 -EntryType Information -Message "Instance $instanceId is not joined to the domain. Joining using SSM $env:SsmName in region $env:Region"

    Try {
        New-SSMAssociation -InstanceId:$instanceId -Name:$env:SsmName -Region $env:Region
        Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 1000 -EntryType Information -Message "Successfully joined $instanceId to the domain. Restarting..."
        Restart-Computer
    }
    Catch [Exception] {
        Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 2000 -EntryType Error -Message "An error occurred joining $instanceId to the domain. $($_.Exception)"
    }
}
Else {
    Write-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source Ec2Config -EventId 1000 -EntryType Information -Message "Instance $instanceId is already joined to the domain."
}
```

I know my config and commands are working, because if I do an application version update on the same environment and the computer doesn't restart from RenameComputer.ps1 because it's already named as desired, JoinDomain.ps1 DOES run and joins the computer to the domain and restarts again.

The documentation (un)clearly says:

```
waitAfterCompletion
Optional. Seconds to wait after the command completes before running the next command. If the system requires a reboot after the command completes, the system reboots after the specified number of seconds elapses. If the system reboots as a result of a command, Elastic Beanstalk will recover. The default value is 60 seconds. You can also specify forever, but the system must reboot before you can run another command.
```

Which suggests that the commands should resume...but they aren't.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this just another poorly documented AWS feature that doesn't really work as advertised?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I can think of:

1. Have you tried renaming "01_Rename.config" to use "-" (hypen) instead of underscore? i.e name **"01-Rename.config"** (i've seen the underscore causes issues for me in elastic beanstalk when scripting Powershell).
2. Also try using a different **"waitAfterCompletion"** value, or remove it completely. Suspect that 0 is enough when EC2 instance is warm (Application version updated, but not after a cold reboot/restart)

Comment: Yes I have. I also found that when using container_commands instead of commands, resumes do happen correctly after restart. For now I've just switched to container_commands. Seems like a bug.